# Is there a way to get job creation date in laravel?

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, jobs

Is there a way to get a queue job's creation date in laravel while executing the job? My queue driver is redis and I can't change that.

Comment: You could pass the current time as a parameter to the job

Comment: Is there any built-in way? @PtrTon

Comment: I'm not sure about Redis, but the database driver can apparently do [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-get-created-at-data-from-jobs-table)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there's no built-in way for getting the job creation date in laravel for redis and as @PtrTon stated, you'd have to store that yourself.